# REGEX Getting 3rd and proceeding lines of text not supposed to

Tags: regex, vba

im typing the target text into a multiline textbox it then gets put into a cell where this code is run. for example when the cell contains this:

```
Hi my name is #Daffy the
duck im not a normal duck
im a talking duck
```

it will return

```
#Daffy
im a talking duck
```

it should return

```
#Daffy
```

This is the code:

```
Sub TIA
    Set xlsNote = Worksheets("NoteRegister")

    Set Rng = xlsNote.Range("B2")

    lastRow = xlsNote.Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = IIf(lastRow < Rng.Row, Rng, Rng.Resize(lastRow + Rng.Row - 1, 3))
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegExp.IgnoreCase = False
    RegExp.Pattern = "[^#]*(#\w+)\s*(.*)"

    For Each Cell In Rng
        Text = Cell
        Do While RegExp.Test(Text) = True
            Tag = RegExp.Replace(Text, "$1")
            If Tag <> "#" Then
                If Not Dict.Exists(Tag) Then Dict.Add Tag, ""
            End If
            Text = RegExp.Replace(Text, "$2")
        Loop
    Next Cell

    xlsNote.Range("E2").Resize(Dict.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dict.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure about vba, but you should probably use the end of line `$`. `"[^#]*(#\w+)\s*(.*)$"`

Comment: Thanks I Tried but it threw up a type mismatch on xlsNote.Range("E2").Resize(Dict.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dict.Keys)

Comment: If all you want is `#Daffy` why not simply `(#\w+)`? Try it here http://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: `(#\w+)(.*)` if you want 2 capture groups, but the 2nd will go on without restriction.

Comment: there can be multiple #**** in each cell on multiple lines

Comment: What breaks the lines up? Your original regex says something like.. capture the first word that starts with #, then find any whitespace that follows, then capture anything. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: As @kcdwayne says, tell us explicitly, not just by example, what you want the regex to return.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to get any hash tagged words within a range on multiple lines within each cell BUT not doubles of the same Hash tagged word hence  "If Not Dict.Exists(Tag) Then Dict.Add Tag,". I am VERY new to REGEX and barely understand it. This code works very well with out multiple lines of text but as soon as there is a new line in the cell it skips the 2nd line then takes the third and proceeding lines.

Comment: The text is first written into a multiline textbox on a userform it is then moved to a cell on a worksheet (Range("A1") = textbox.text) so the lines are broken up in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Afer much testing (thankyou @kcdwayne for suggesting the Regex101 editor) I worked out what the problem was! What was happening was "(.*)" was capturing everything as the "$2" match BUT it was not capturing the new lines! so i changed it to this ([^/]*). That little bugger matches EVERYTHING so when the "$1" match is made the target text becomes the "$2" match so basically it widdles down the target text until no more tags are found then moves on to the next cell.

Example Target Text

```
    My name is #Daffy the duck, 
    I am not a #normal duck 
    I am a #talking duck
```

Return will be

```
$1  #Daffy
$2  the duck,
    I am not a #normal duck
    I am a #talking duck
```

Now the new target text becomes $2

Does that make any sense? I hope it does because that fixes the problem! Thanks for the help kcdwayne